# How to undistort points in camera shot coordinates and obtain corresponding undistorted image coordinates?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I use OpenCV to undestort set of points after camera calibration.
The code follows.

```
const int npoints = 2; // number of point specified 

// Points initialization. 
// Only 2 ponts in this example, in real code they are read from file.
float input_points[npoints][2] = {{0,0}, {2560, 1920}}; 

CvMat * src = cvCreateMat(1, npoints, CV_32FC2);
CvMat * dst = cvCreateMat(1, npoints, CV_32FC2);

// fill src matrix
float * src_ptr = (float*)src->data.ptr;
for (int pi = 0; pi < npoints; ++pi) {
    for (int ci = 0; ci < 2; ++ci) {
        *(src_ptr + pi * 2 + ci) = input_points[pi][ci];
    }
}

cvUndistortPoints(src, dst, &camera1, &distCoeffs1);
```

After the code above `dst` contains following numbers:

```
-8.82689655e-001 -7.05507338e-001 4.16228324e-001 3.04863811e-001
```

which are too small in comparison with numbers in `src`.

At the same time if I undistort image via the call:

```
cvUndistort2( srcImage, dstImage, &camera1, &dist_coeffs1 );
```

I receive good undistorted image which means that pixel coordinates are not modified so drastically in comparison with separate points.

How to obtain the same undistortion for specific points as for images?
Thanks.

Comment: are you sure camera1 and camera are the same?

Comment: yes, the same - I have fixed question. Thanks you for pointing out. Moreover initially I receive such behaviour in EmguCV and then tried to figure out where such behaviour is introduced: in OpenCV or EmguCV itself. It appeared in OpenCV.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The points should be "unnormalized" using camera matrix.

More specifically, after call of `cvUndistortPoints` following transformation should be also added:

```
double fx = CV_MAT_ELEM(camera1, double, 0, 0);
double fy = CV_MAT_ELEM(camera1, double, 1, 1);
double cx = CV_MAT_ELEM(camera1, double, 0, 2);
double cy = CV_MAT_ELEM(camera1, double, 1, 2);

float * dst_ptr = (float*)dst->data.ptr;
for (int pi = 0; pi < npoints; ++pi) {
    float& px = *(dst_ptr + pi * 2);
    float& py = *(dst_ptr + pi * 2 + 1);
    // perform transformation. 
    // In fact this is equivalent to multiplication to camera matrix
    px = px * fx + cx;
    py = py * fy + cy;
}
```

More info on camera matrix at OpenCV ['Camera Calibration and 3D Reconstruction'](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)

**UPDATE:**

Following C++ function call should work as well:

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> inputDistortedPoints = ...
std::vector<cv::Point2f> outputUndistortedPoints;
cv::Mat cameraMatrix = ...
cv::Mat distCoeffs = ...

cv::undistortPoints(inputDistortedPoints, outputUndistortedPoints, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, cv::noArray(), cameraMatrix);
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be your matrix size :)

OpenCV expects a vector of points - a column or a row matrix with two channels. But because your input matrix is only 2 pts, and the number of channels is also 1, it cannot figure out what's the input, row or colum.

So, fill a longer input mat with bogus values, and keep only the first:

```
const int npoints = 4; // number of point specified 

// Points initialization. 
// Only 2 ponts in this example, in real code they are read from file.
float input_points[npoints][4] = {{0,0}, {2560, 1920}}; // the rest will be set to 0

CvMat * src = cvCreateMat(1, npoints, CV_32FC2);
CvMat * dst = cvCreateMat(1, npoints, CV_32FC2);

// fill src matrix
float * src_ptr = (float*)src->data.ptr;
for (int pi = 0; pi < npoints; ++pi) {
    for (int ci = 0; ci < 2; ++ci) {
        *(src_ptr + pi * 2 + ci) = input_points[pi][ci];
    }
}

cvUndistortPoints(src, dst, &camera1, &distCoeffs1);
```

**EDIT**

While OpenCV specifies undistortPoints accept only 2-channel input, actually, it accepts

- 1-column, 2-channel, multi-row mat or (and this case is not documented)
- 2 column, multi-row, 1-channel mat or
- multi-column, 1 row, 2-channel mat

(as seen in undistort.cpp, line 390)

But a bug inside (or lack of available info), makes it wrongly mix the second one with the third one, when the number of columns is 2. So, your data is considered a 2-column, 2-row, 1-channel.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 1 channel? I use constant CV_32FC2 in cvCreateMat, which means 2 channels. Thanks.

Comment: I have looked at the source code of the undistortPoints() func, and the documentation is wrong. Look at the edit above for details, please

Answer (score 0):

I also reach this problems, and I take some time to research an finally understand.

[image]

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmR5P.jpg)
You see the formula above, in the open system, distort operation is before camera matrix, so the process order is:

image_distorted ->camera_matrix -> un-distort function->camera_matrix->back to image_undistorted.

So you need a small fix to and  camera1 again.

Mat eye3 = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);

cvUndistortPoints(src, dst, &camera1, &distCoeffs1,  **&eye3,&camera1**);

Otherwise, if the last two parameters is empty, It would be project to a Normalized image coordinate.

See codes: opencv-3.4.0-src\modules\imgproc\src\undistort.cpp :297
cvUndistortPointsInternal()